# Faulting application name: w3wp.exe on IIS7 and PHP Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, isapi-rewrite

I try to run a website with Helicon Isapi Rewrite 3 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with IIS 7.5 installed. The website is using PHP 5.2.16 on ISAPI mode. I use the `request_uri.php` solution (see code) for the bug in IIS.

The server error I get is: 404 - File or directory not found.

With in the Windows Application log this message:

Faulting application path: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe`

Faulting module path: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll`

I tried DebugDiag to find something, but it didn't give any more information. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? Thanks.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL']))
    {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was not found, because of a security issue.

In IIS under Sites=>Authentication=>Anonymous Authentication=>Edit... and then I turned the anonymous user identity to Application Pool identity and it worked again.

Hopefully other users will find this helpfull.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best idea to run PHP in ISAPI mode. It's likely to fail. Please try running it in FastCGI mode. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942712

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation along with your link?